# Suppose l1 and l2 are skew lines in the space E3. Is it true that lines PQ, where P ∈ l1, Q ∈ l2, sweep the whole space?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Suppose l1 and l2 are skew lines in the space E3. Is it true that lines PQ, where P ∈ l1, Q ∈ l2, sweep the whole space?

My idea that it is not true due to the fact that we can provide counterexample: can take parallellines in 3d space and then the line PQ, where P ∈ l1, Q ∈ l2, can not sweep the whole space. Is that true or am I missing something?

Comment: Take a point $M$ of the plane containing $l1$ and parallel to $l2$ and $M$ doesn't belong to $l1$. There is no line $PQ$ such that $M \in PQ$.

Comment: Parallel lines are not skew, so your counterexample isn’t one. In projective 3-space (where every plane intersects every line) your result is true.